# print double quotes in shell programming

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I want to print double quotes using echo statement in shell programming.

**Example**:

```
echo "$1,$2,$3,$4";
```

prints `xyz,123,abc,pqrs`

How to print `"xyz","123","abc","pqrs";`

I had tried to place double quotes in echo statement but its not being printed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just have to quote them:

```
echo "\"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\""
```

As noted [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters
>   ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see
>   Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when
>   followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or
>   newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of
>   these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without
>   a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted
>   within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled,
>   history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double
>   quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’
>   is not removed.
>
> The special parameters ‘*’ and ‘@’ have special meaning when in double
>   quotes (see Shell Parameter Expansion).

Comment: It should be `printf` not `print`

Comment: You probably meant to say `echo` instead of `print`!

Comment: Yes `print` command is used instead of `echo` in `ksh` but the question is asked for `bash`, you should edit your answer as well or atleast specify the `ksh` limitation

Comment: @snyder Changed the obvious. I'm not sure how that would make a difference since the topic's solution is generally about quoting.

Comment: @konsolebox did you read the comment by Raju? that's the difference it will make and also the future readers will try your command and will get the same error.

Comment: Can you suggest me a online source for shell programming@konsolebox @synder

Comment: @Raju I always prefer referring the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for starters. It seems updated as well.

Comment: @konsolebox The ABS is problematic; I like to refer newcomers to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist instead

Answer (score 16):

Use `printf`, no escaping is required:

```
printf '"%s","%s","%s","%s";\n' "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
```

and the trailing `;` gets printed too!

Comment: Only that printf is not compatible to all shells.

Comment: Hmm.. `printf` is defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).

Comment: Yeah, but not in System V.

Comment: The fact that System V is not POSIX-compliant in no way detracts from this answer. Besides, the question is tagged `bash`, so the operating system should be irrelevant.

Comment: @chepner Sometimes we can't really assert that a thread is specific to `bash` just because of the tag since there are many reasons why it could have been added there. Some just tag it implying that bash is shell itself while some just place it for more audience. Sometimes relying on the title could be more accurate.

Comment: Maybe explain that the trailing `;` gets printed because it's also inside the quotes, not specifically because you used `printf`.

Comment: if $1, $2, $3 or $4 has spaces your command will not do the job

Answer (score 4):

You should escape the `"` to make it visible in the output, you can do this :

```
echo \""$1"\",\""$2"\",\""$3"\",\""$4"\"
```

Comment: The first version runs into issues if any of the positional parameters contains a `%` character; the second works.

Comment: Your argument should also be placed around a single pair of doublequotes: `echo ""\"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\""` or else variables would be subject to word splitting with IFS and possible pathname expansion.